# Use value from one form as value for another form in redirected template (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have two models

```py
def CarModel(models.Model):
   type = models.CharField()
   price = models.FloatField()
   img = models.URLfield()



def WrongCar(models.Model):
    wrong_type = models.CharField()
    correct_type = models.CharField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

I have a product-list of, say, cars using the `CarModel` but if a car is classified wrong, the user should be able to correct it by filling out the fields in `WrongCar` by clicking on a button called "correct type", then the user is redirected to the `wrong_car`-template where the fields from `WrongCar` are such they can be filled out. When that happens, `wrong_type` should then automatically be filled out with the value `type` from the `CarModel` such that the user only should fill in `correct_type` and `price`. I think I can extract it from the `request` object, but I really dont have any idea of how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass values through redirects storing them in request.session (dictionary), for example:

correct_car_view.py

```
request.session['wrong_car_type'] = 'type_you_want'
return redirect(reverse('wrong_car_url'))
```

wrong_car_view.py

```
try:
    wrong_car_type = request.session['wrong_car_type']
except KeyError:
    wrong_car_type = None
else:
    del request.session['wrong_car_type']
```

Comment: I ended up using the `pk` key combined with `MyClass.get.object()` instead - although your answer might work as well